# Can I configure, which DNS server Tor should use to resolve proxy.hostname.com?

Tags: pre-tor-proxy

As far I understand, for the most part, Tor usually does not use system DNS.

When a http proxy is configured in torrc, Tor obviously has to resolve proxy.hostname.com to a IP. And doing the resolving untorified, over clearnet, because Tor needs to know how to connect to the proxy in the first place before it can connect to the Tor network.

Can I explicitly configure which DNS server Tor should use for these DNS requests?

This would be useful in setups, where is no system DNS resolver by design. Such as when the system is only supposed to emit Tor traffic, where everything but the Tor process is forced to use Tor.

Answer (score 1):

What about preventing the DNS resolution from happening by using the proxy IP instead of the proxy hostname in torrc?

Comment: That would work. But it's a bit cumbersome, breaks when the IP changes, and might get detected by the proxy.